# ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS in not firing

Tags: android

I just wanted to disable battery optimization in my app. I used the below snippet

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
String packageName = context.getPackageName();
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
if (pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName))
   intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS);
else {
    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
}
context.startActivity(intent);
```

The snippet is firing but not showing any option to disable battery optimization. And not showing any error in the log. Please help

Comment: Do you have the `REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Thank you dude u saved my day

Comment: This code is not working in Android wear OS.How can I enable battery optimization feature in Android smart watch?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ensure you have the `REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` permission defined in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you define the `android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` permission.

Additionally, it seemed not to work when I declared the permission with the `<uses-permission>`-tag. When I defined it using the `<uses-permission-sdk-23>`-tag, it worked as intended.