# Dialog for intent Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS

Tags: android, android-intent, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-doze

I am using Android 6 with Cyanogenmod  and when I am starting the following intent, then nothing happens!

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Constants.IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS_MIN_BUILD) {
                    String packageName = getPackageName();
                    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                    if (!pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS).setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
                        try {
                            startActivity(intent);
    ...
```

Should the dialog for the Battery optimisation come up? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that it is likely that your app will get removed from the store if you use this functionality

Comment: No,  they won't,  because I only want to show up the dialog and the user does it himself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ACTION\_REQUEST\_IGNORE\_BATTERY\_OPTIMIZATIONS in not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40434858/action-request-ignore-battery-optimizations-in-not-firing)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to have this line in your manifest:

```
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
```

Comment: ......This is awesome solution to get alert for battery optimization settings......But I had read some where that if writing the above permission in the manifest file google play store will reject the app from the play store....it is true ?

Comment: I read the same thing and we debated this within out development team before adding this. It is in our Play Store alpha channel and there's been no sign of Google pulling the app so far. I will definitely report back if our app gets pulled out of the store.

Comment: As a followup I'm happy to report that after 8 months in production there are no signs of Google Play objecting to the use of this permission.